# Navigation bar , remove strange space

Tags: swift, xcode, listview, swiftui, navigationview

in my project i'm try to remove the ugly space between my top bar Rectangle() and my List with NavigationView.

I don't know why between those 2 View SwiftUi create space.

as you can see from the picture below once I add the NavigationView it appear a strange space.

I would like my NavigationBarITEM touch my Rectangle()

if I use the offset() it works, but it sound strange.. should be by default they are inside a VStack

Thanks

```
   VStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: g.size.height/12)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                        NavigationView{
                            List{
                                ForEach(self.dm.storage) { item in
                                    Text(item.airportData.aptICAO)
                                }

                            }  .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
                        }
                    }
```

[image: Navigation View space]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have `NavigationView` above in view hierarchy, so you don't need second one

```
VStack{
    Rectangle()
        .frame(height: g.size.height/12)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                                     // << no additional NavigationView needed
        List{
            ForEach(self.dm.storage) { item in
                Text(item.airportData.aptICAO)
            }

        }  .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
}
```